# pageblock render in salesforce1

Tags: visualforce

How can I fix this render of a pageblock table in salesforce1:
[image]

the table go outside the page border.
The visulforce is:

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Possibili Lead" id="Possibili" rendered="{!IF(Lead.Company =null , false, true)}" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Lead" id="possibilita" collapsible="false" columns="1" >
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!PossibiliLead}" var="pl">
            <apex:column headerValue="Action">
            <apex:outputLink value="/{!pl.Id}" style="color:blue; padding:2px; text-decoration: none" >View</apex:outputLink>
            <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Lead.Edit, pl.Id, null, true)}" style="color:blue; padding:2px; text-decoration: none">Edit</apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!pl.Company}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!pl.LastName}"/> 
            <apex:column value="{!pl.Email}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!pl.Phone}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!pl.Website}"/>                             
            </apex:pageblockTable>     
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
            <apex:commandButton value="Nuovo Lead" oncomplete="go();" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

I alredy check the checkbox "ready for Salesforce1" on the visualforce page info. Help me please

Comment: You need to create html table using and then apply bootstrap CSS.

Comment: In this case we always create 2 view one for desktop and another mobile.. based on the user device we display the view..